# Service does not work?

Tags: android, service, gps

I had service that run by BrodcastReceiver which suppose to run and give me the GPS data that I requested and I stopped it after I did what suppose to be done, but I notice that It did not provide me with the data that requested and did not stop too , any body can help me in figuring out my problem
the code is below and the service tested in real device:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class GpsService extends Service implements LocationListener{
    static LocationManager mlocManager;

    }    
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        mlocManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0,this);

    }

        @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)
    {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();
    String Text = "My current location is: " +"Latitud = " + loc.getLatitude() +"Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();
   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    // Here to stop the service and make it finish its task
    SystemClock.sleep(40000);
    // stop the Gps system by this application
    mlocManager.removeUpdates(this);
    //Here to stop the service by itself
    stopSelf();

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Gps Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
    }


}
```

Comment: Husam this is not good practice to use SystemClock.sleep(40000);
 for making wait. you will use Timer for better result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. do you have the correct permissions on the manifest?
2. why do you make the service sleep and for so long? the service works on the UI thread , and such a thing can cause the service to be killed automatically by the system after about 5 seconds because the ui thread doesn't respond.
3. if you wish to delay the stopping and/or showing of the toast , either use Handler (and postDelayed) , or use asyncTask , or something of your own .
4. do you have the gps turned on? have you considered using a fake location app or the emulator for this task ?
5. good luck .